# Анимация контейнера вьюх

Tags: android, анимация

Есть контейнер с вьюхами (

```
 <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/view_contain_block_parameters"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/hint"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/searchParametersText"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="#006889"
            android:layout_marginBottom="19dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="17dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="19dp"
            android:text="+Параметры поиска" />

        <include
            android:id="@+id/block_search_parameters"
            layout="@layout/searching_parameters_block"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:visibility="gone" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

), нужно добавить TranslateAnimaton так, что бы блок в инклуде появлялся медленно, выалывая сверху - вниз, когда видимость програмно становиться VISBLE, и "задвигался" назад, когда GONE

Answer (score 0):

Решил задачу, удалить лишний `LinearLayout`, добавить         `view_contain_block_parameters.layoutTransition.setDuration(700L)`, а в единственный оставшийся лайаут добавить строку `android:animateLayoutChanges="true"`. Или, через `ScaleAnimation`, но тоже удалив `LinearLayout`.